# Expand multiple pandas columns in snakemake to iterrate rows

Tags: python, pandas, snakemake

I'm trying to use 2 columns in the same pandas dataframe as the basis to generate output files via snakemake.

A minimal example of my code is like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':['A','B','C']})

rule all:
    input:
        expand('data/{c1}/{c2}.tsv', c1 = df['col1'], c2 = df['col2'])

rule make_files:
    output:
        "data/{c1}/{c2}.tsv"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

The issue I have is that my desired output is 3 files that would be the result of iterating row by row (i.e., 1/A.tsv, 2/B.tsv, 3/C.tsv), however this current script gives is 9 files that are the permutations of my rows (i.e., 1/A.tsv, 1/B.tsv, 1/C.tsv, 2/A.tsv, 2/B.tsv, 2/C.tsv, 3/A.tsv, 3/B.tsv, 3/C.tsv).

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is one potential fix:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':['A','B','C']})

foo = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    foo.append('{}/{}'.format(row['col1'],row['col2']))

rule all:
    input:
        expand('data/{c1}.tsv', c1 = foo )

rule make_files:
    output:
        "data/{c1}.tsv"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

This'll give you the desired 3 folders. Essentially you've just created a list of strings that contains the combinations you wanted to make from your 2 columns.